# Moving up dates with app script but it returns different format?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running a script that will move up a date in each cell. I want it to move all the selected dates up x days. When I run the function it works but changes the format of the date:

"J" is just simple dates "7/9/2019" And I am trying to run the script (which emails a copy of my invoice to the client, that part works great)

```
function updatePM(sheet, email){
  var value;
  var datevalue
  var emails = sheet.getRange("G3:G" +  
sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++)
    if (emails[i][0] == email){
  value = sheet.getRange("L" + (i+3)).getValue() + 1
  datevalue = sheet.getRange("J" + (i+3)).getValue() - 1
  sheet.getRange("L" + (i+3)).setValue(value);
  sheet.getRange("J" + (i+3)).setValue(datevalue);
```

So I think it is the line "datevalue = sheet.getRange("J" + (i+3)).getValue() - 1" that needs to be changed, I have never moved a date and not sure how to keep the same format.

Comment: What does the date it's returning look like?

Comment: Starts like ":7/7/2019" and changes to "1562471999999"

Answer (score 1):

Sheets and Apps Script use different bases for time units so you're getting back Unix Time after the script. Try changing:

```
value = sheet.getRange("L" + (i+3)).getValue() + 1
datevalue = sheet.getRange("J" + (i+3)).getValue() - 1
sheet.getRange("L" + (i+3)).setValue(value);
sheet.getRange("J" + (i+3)).setValue(datevalue);
```

to:

```
value = sheet.getRange("L" + (i + 3)).getValue() + 86400000
datevalue = sheet.getRange("J" + (i + 3)).getValue() - 86400000
sheet.getRange("L" + (i + 3)).setValue(new Date(value)).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sheet.getRange("J" + (i + 3)).setValue(new Date(datevalue)).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

You can see the available Date formats [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_and_time_format_patterns).

Comment: Wouldn't this set the date to the time the script run rather than the value from `datevalue` like the original script did?

Comment: @ross Yes you're right thank you, I forgot to set the value of the Date. Updated my answer.

Comment: Now I am about to go research this as I have never touched unix time, but if anyone wants to answer that would be great. What about multiple days, I don't understand the "86400000" as I have never touched something like this and still learning.

Comment: @JohnVelella Unix time is a date format which counts the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, minus leap-seconds. It’s a commonly used computer time standard, Google however uses milliseconds instead of seconds. 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now. But since I am trying to learn to use this properly can you tell me why when I change the 86400000 to 172800000 (Double the 86400000) it goes way off instead of moving up 2 days? It changed the date from 7/7/2019 to 12/31/1969.

Comment: OK, it doesn't make sense, I use this (cells updated) and I get 12/31/1969:

Comment: function updatePM(sheet, email){
  var value;
  var datevalue
  var emails = sheet.getRange("H3:H" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++)
    if (emails[i][0] == email){
      value = sheet.getRange("M" + (i+3)).getValue() + 1
      datevalue = sheet.getRange("K" + (i + 3)).getValue() + 86400000
      sheet.getRange("M" + (i+3)).setValue(value);
      sheet.getRange("K" + (i + 3)).setValue(new Date(datevalue)).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: The added 1 at the end of `value = sheet.getRange("L" + (i + 3)).getValue() + 1` is going to change the value only by one millisecond so the date shouldn't change. Which column has what type of data in? I didn't run into any issues running the code in my answer with email addresses in column G and dates in J and L. I trued doubling 86400000 to 172800000 like you said but that's also returning a 2 day difference like I'd expect. Try putting the outputs of your dates before and after reading from the cells using `Logger.log()` to see in which format the date is kept in at what stage in the code.